# Using Swagger with Multiple Controllers with Same Url but Different Response Types

Tags: controller, swagger, response, swagger-ui

I am using Swagger UI for interactive API documentation in my project. I have multiple controllers with the same URL, the logic for both are different and the response types are different - one produces JSON, another one produces text/CSV. Swagger is considering only one of them. What is the way for Swagger to recognize both?

Comment: Looks like its a bug in Swagger. You should raise a bug.

Comment: Is there no way I can do it? I am using swagger.io, not springfox swagger.